# Pandas read_csv: Columns are being imported as rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, import

**Edit**: I believe this was all user error. I have been typing `df.T` by default, and it just occurred to me that this is very likely the TRANSPOSE output. By typing `df`, the data frame is output normally (headers as columns). Thank you for those who stepped up to try and help. In the end, it was just my misunderstanding of pandas language..

**Original Post**

I'm not sure if I am making a simple mistake but the columns in a .csv file are being imported as rows using `pd.read_csv`. The dataframe turns out to be 5 rows by 2000 columns. I am importing only 5 columns out of 14 so I set up a list to hold the names of the columns I want. They match exactly those in the .csv file. What am I doing wrong here?

```
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

fp = 'C:/Users/my/file/path'
os.chdir(fp)

cols_to_use = ['VCOMPNO_CURRENT', 'MEASUREMENT_DATETIME',
               'EQUIPMENT_NUMBER', 'AXLE', 'POSITION']

df = pd.read_csv('measurement_file.csv',
                 usecols=cols_to_use,
                 dtype={'EQUIPMENT_NUMBER': np.int,
                        'AXLE': np.int},
                 parse_dates=[2],
                 infer_datetime_format=True)
```

Output:

```
                                    0  ...            2603
VCOMPNO_CURRENT                T92656  ...          T5M247
MEASUREMENT_DATETIME  7/26/2018 13:04  ...  9/21/2019 3:21
EQUIPMENT_NUMBER                  208  ...             537
AXLE                                1  ...               6
POSITION                            L  ...               R

[5 rows x 2000 columns]
```

Thank you.

Edit: To note, if I import the entire .csv with the standard `pd.read_csv('measurement_file.csv')`, the columns are imported properly.

Edit 2: Sample csv:

```
VCOMPNO_CURRENT,MEASUREMENT_DATETIME,REPAIR_ORDER_NUMBER,EQUIPMENT_NUMBER,AXLE,POSITION,FLANGE_THICKNESS,FLANGE_HEIGHT,FLANGE_SLOPE,DIAMETER,RO_NUMBER_SRC,CL,VCOMPNO_AT_MEAS,VCOMPNO_SRC
T92656,10/19/2018 7:11,5653054,208,1,L,26.59,27.34,6.52,691.3,OPTIMESS_DATA,2MTA ,T71614 ,RO_EQUIP     
T92656,10/19/2018 7:11,5653054,208,1,R,26.78,27.25,6.64,691.5,OPTIMESS_DATA,2MTA ,T71614 ,RO_EQUIP     
T92656,10/19/2018 7:11,5653054,208,2,L,26.6,27.13,6.49,691.5,OPTIMESS_DATA,2MTA ,T71614 ,RO_EQUIP     
T92656,10/19/2018 7:11,5653054,208,2,R,26.61,27.45,6.75,691.6,OPTIMESS_DATA,2MTA ,T71614 ,RO_EQUIP     
T7L672,10/19/2018 7:11,5653054,208,3,L,26.58,27.14,6.58,644.4,OPTIMESS_DATA,2CTC ,T7L672 ,BOTH         
T7L672,10/19/2018 7:11,5653054,208,3,R,26.21,27.44,6.17,644.5,OPTIMESS_DATA,2CTC ,T7L672 ,BOTH
```

Comment: can you add how is your csv??

Comment: how do you display it ? Show part of csv file.

Comment: cannot recreate. could you share a sample of the csv?

Comment: Added a sample of the file.

Comment: Try to export this partial data to CSV file, `df.to_csv(File name.csv)`, and check the file, may be the result help to guess the problem.

Comment: It gets exported with the columns as rows. It's killing me why the dataframe is being transposed during import. I am pulling in a smaller, separate .csv file and it is getting imported just fine. Could it be table size at all??

Answer (score 1):

A simple workaround here is to just to take the transpose of the dataframe. 
[Link to Pandas Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html#pandas.DataFrame.transpose)

```
df = pd.DataFrame.transpose(df)
```

Comment: Thank you. A workaround is fine but I am wondering what about my script is making Python import my columns as rows. To note, if I import the entire .csv with the standard ```pd.read_csv('measurement_file.csv')```, the columns are imported properly.

Comment: How is the file delimited? I have seen that sometimes the read_csv will read in tab delimited files in strange ways.

Comment: The file is comma delimited.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try like this?

```
import pandas as pd

dataset = pd.read_csv('yourfile.csv')

#filterhere
dataset = dataset[cols_to_use]
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, it filters down to the columns of interest but puts them into rows.